# $.ajax JSONP on crossdomain XML file

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to read XML from a crossdomain source and im having trouble getting the callback response into a string. If i look at the console in chrome i get 'Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/xml: http://mysite.com:2000/g7?callback=jQuery17209426668137311935_1344441190139&_=1344441194148'

Then followed by 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <'

What am i missing here?

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://mysite.com:2000/g7',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    mimeType: 'text/xml'
});

Comment: It's trying to interpret the XML as Javascript. A simple fix would be to send back XML wrapped up in a JSON object. Or if you're real clever you'll convert the XML to JSON so it's good to go from the start. You will need access to the data source for any solution.

Answer (score 2):

> What am i missing here?

The fact that JSONP infers JSON response wrapped in a callback. This cannot work with XML. So you will have to modify the remote server side script so that it returns JSONP, not XML. For example the response could look like this:

```
callback({ xml: '<node>foo bar</node>' });
```

But if the remote server sends directly XML you cannot use AJAX to invoke it due to the same origin policy restriction.

Comment: Well i thought that i had read somewhere that i could use the .ajax command to get the XML from the url by using the callback. I know im using a JSONP command for XML but maybe i misunderstood the other article i had seen. Ill try to find it again.

So i guess my real question would be, the server that is returning the XML, i have no control over so i cannot get it to return a JSON string. Is there any way to remotely parse an XML page?

Comment: Yes, you probably misunderstood the article. You cannot send cross domain AJAX requests due to the same origin policy restriction that's built into the browsers. One possible workaround is to use JSONP but the remote server must support it. If it doesn't you could write a server side script on your domain that will serve as a bridge between your domain and the remote domain. Then send the AJAX request to your own server side script that will query the remote domain and return the XML.

Comment: Ok, thats what i thought i was going to have to do. I was looking at some examples of PHP scripts that would use 'file_get_contents($xmlUrl)' but ill have to do more research on that. I was having problems actually returning data from 'file_get_contents', instead i have seen people use 'cURL'  Does this sound correct?

Comment: Yes, this sounds absolutely right. A PHP script that sends a request to the remote domain to retrieve the XML and write this XML to the response. Then send the AJAX request to your own PHP script. This time you don't need to specify any jsonp data types.